# How to generate pdf file using database entry in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a pdf using database entries of a django model (basically the data was taken input by html form and submitted in database by some view) and store it in the file field of the same model.
But none of the solutions posted related to this topic show how to achieve this task(or perhaps i m not able to find it out).

This is my view related to storing the form entry in database

```
 def apply_purchase(request):
        current_user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)
        print(current_user)
        user_details = ExtraInfo.objects.all().filter(user=current_user).first()
        print(user_details)
        user_type = HoldsDesignation.objects.all().filter(user=current_user).first()
        print(user_type)
        usertype=str.split(str(user_type))
        print(usertype)
        # Academics Admin Check
        user=usertype[0]
        #desig_id = Designation.objects.all().filter(name='Faculty')
        #print(desig_id)

        if(user == "student"):
            return HttpResponse('You are not authorised to view this page')

        if request.method == 'POST':
            item_name=request.POST.get('item_name')
            quantity=request.POST.get('quantity')
            expected_cost=int(request.POST.get('expected_cost'))

            if  expected_cost >=25000 and expected_cost <= 250000 :
                local_comm_mem1_id=request.POST.get('local_comm_mem1_id')
                local_comm_mem2_id=request.POST.get('local_comm_mem2_id')
                local_comm_mem3_id=request.POST.get('local_comm_mem3_id')

            nature_of_item1= 1 if request.POST.get('nature_of_item1') == 'on' else 0
            nature_of_item2= 1 if request.POST.get('nature_of_item2') == 'on' else 0
            purpose=request.POST.get('purpose')



     expected_purchase_date=request.POST.get('expected_purchase_date')
            a = apply_for_purchase.objects.create(
                    item_name=item_name,
                    quantity=int(quantity),
                    expected_cost=expected_cost,
                    nature_of_item1=nature_of_item1,
                    nature_of_item2=nature_of_item2,
                    purpose=purpose,
                    # budgetary_head_id = budgetary_head_id,
                    # inspecting_authority_id=inspecting_authority_id,
                    expected_purchase_date= expected_purchase_date,
                    indentor_name=user_details,

            )
            a.save()
```

I m a newbie in django so any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-pdf/), you should be able to achieve this using ReportLab. In order to output the PDF the way you want it, you'll have to customize the way the PDF gets drawn.

Here is a short code [snippet](https://www.reportlab.com/snippets/17/) from ReportLab which is hopefully what you need.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rlextra.rml2pdf import rml2pdf
import cStringIO

def getPDF(request):
    """Returns PDF as a binary stream."""

    # Use your favourite templating language here to create the RML string.
    # The generated document might depend on the web request parameters,
    # database lookups and so on - we'll leave that up to you.
    rml = getRML(request)  

    buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

    rml2pdf.go(rml, outputFileName=buf)
    buf.reset()
    pdfData = buf.read()

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response.write(pdfData)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
    return response
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more on how to customize the pdf?